# OpenGL texture tilted

Tags: opengl, textures

When I load a texture in OpenGL and this has one (`GL_ALPHA`) or three components per pixel (`GL_RGB`), the texture appears tilted. What makes this happen?

As additional detail, the relation width/height seems to affect. For example, an image of 1366x768(683/384) appears tilted while an image of 1920x1080(16/9) is mapped correctly.

[image: slanted image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably a padding/alignment issue.

GL, by default, expects rows of pixels to be padded to a multiple of 4 bytes. A 1366 wide texture with 1 byte or 3 byte wide pixels, will not be naturally 4 byte aligned.

Possible fixes for this are:

- Tell GL how your texture is packed, using (for example) `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`
- Change the dimensions of your texture, such that the padding matches without changing anything
- Change the loading of your texture, such that the padding is consistent with what GL expects

Comment: I didn't ask the question, but It really helps me!! Thanks!