# openGL render different on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-3.0

[image: opengl rendered on iPhone]
[image]
I created an `iOS` app using `OpenGL` to render yuv420p from ffmpeg.
It works fine on `iPad`, but on `iPhone`, it looks like the image below,
the picture looks italic and  the right bottom triangle part like below should be on the left.
I can not found the reason, has anyone met this before?
does `OpenGL` on iPad and `iPhone` different?
below is my `OpenGL` view. `SDL_Overlay` is a struct that holds YUV plane data from ffmpeg.

```
#import "EAGLView.h"

// Uniform index.
enum
{
    UNIFORM_Y,
    UNIFORM_U,
    UNIFORM_V,
    NUM_UNIFORMS
};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];

// Attribute index.
enum
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX,
    ATTRIB_TEXCOORD,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
};

const GLubyte VertexIndexStruct[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

@interface EAGLView () {
    // The pixel dimensions of the CAEAGLLayer.
    GLint _backingWidth;
    GLint _backingHeight;

    EAGLContext *m_context;

    GLuint _frameBufferHandle;
    GLuint _colorBufferHandle;

    BOOL _pause;
}
@property GLuint program;

- (void)setupBuffers;
- (BOOL)loadShaders;
- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type URL:(NSURL *)URL;
- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog;
- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog;
@end

@implementation EAGLView

+(Class) layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *) notification {
    _pause = YES;
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *) notification {
    _pause = NO;
}

-(void) destroyFrameBuffer {
    // tear down GL
    if (_frameBufferHandle) {
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &_frameBufferHandle);
        _frameBufferHandle = 0;
    }

    if (_colorBufferHandle) {
        glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &_colorBufferHandle);
        _colorBufferHandle = 0;
    }

    if(self.program) {
        glDeleteProgram(self.program);
    }
}

-(void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self setupGL];
}

# pragma mark - OpenGL setup
- (void)setupGL {
    [self destroyFrameBuffer];
    self.contentScaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
    [eaglLayer setContentsScale:self.contentScaleFactor];
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = @{ kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                                      kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat : kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8};

    if(m_context) {
        [m_context release];
    }
    m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];
    if(!m_context) {
        m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    }
    if (!m_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context] || ![self loadShaders]) {
        return;
    }

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context];
    [self setupBuffers];
    [self loadShaders];

    glUseProgram(self.program);

    // 0 and 1 are the texture IDs of _lumaTexture and _chromaTexture respectively.
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_Y], 0);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_U], 1);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_V], 2);
}

#pragma mark - Utilities
- (void)setupBuffers {
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBufferHandle);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferHandle);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorBufferHandle);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle);

    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
    [eaglLayer setContentsScale:self.contentScaleFactor];
    [m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle);
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self destroyFrameBuffer];

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -  OpenGL ES 2 shader compilation
- (BOOL)loadShaders {
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader;
    NSURL *vertShaderURL, *fragShaderURL;

    // Create the shader program.
    self.program = glCreateProgram();

    // Create and compile the vertex shader.
    vertShaderURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"shader" withExtension:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER URL:vertShaderURL]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"shader" withExtension:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER URL:fragShaderURL]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(self.program, vertShader);

    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(self.program, fragShader);

    // Bind attribute locations. This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(self.program, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(self.program, ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, "texCoord");

    // Link the program.
    if (![self linkProgram:self.program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", self.program);

        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (self.program) {
            glDeleteProgram(self.program);
            self.program = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    // Get uniform locations.
    uniforms[UNIFORM_Y] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "SamplerY");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_U] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "SamplerU");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_V] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "SamplerV");

    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(self.program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(self.program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type URL:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *sourceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (sourceString == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }

    GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;
    source = (GLchar *)[sourceString UTF8String];

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        glDeleteShader(*shader);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog {
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(prog);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program link log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog {
    GLint logLength, status;

    glValidateProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(CGSize) renderSize {
    return CGSizeMake(_backingWidth/self.contentScaleFactor, _backingHeight/self.contentScaleFactor);
}

-(void) render:(SDL_Overlay*) overlay {
    if(_pause) {
        return;
    }
    //Create Y and UV textures from the pixel buffer
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uniforms[UNIFORM_Y]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 overlay->w,
                 overlay->h,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 overlay->data[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // U-plane.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uniforms[UNIFORM_U]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 overlay->w/2,
                 overlay->h/2,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 overlay->data[1]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // V-plane.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uniforms[UNIFORM_V]);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 overlay->w/2,
                 overlay->h/2,
                 0,
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 overlay->data[2]);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferHandle);

    CGFloat ratio = (CGFloat)overlay->w / overlay->h;
    GLfloat actualWidth = _backingWidth;
    GLfloat actualHeight = actualWidth / ratio;
    if(actualHeight > _backingHeight) {
        actualHeight = _backingHeight;
        actualWidth = actualHeight * ratio;
    }

    // Set the view port to the entire view.
    glViewport((_backingWidth - actualWidth) / 2,
               (_backingHeight - actualHeight) / 2,
               actualWidth,
               actualHeight);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use shader program.
    glUseProgram(self.program);
    /*
     The quad vertex data defines the region of 2D plane onto which we draw our pixel buffers.
     Vertex data formed using (-1,-1) and (1,1) as the bottom left and top right coordinates respectively, covers the entire screen.
     */
    GLfloat quadVertexData [] = {
        1, -1,
        1, 1,
        -1, 1,
        -1, -1
    };

    // Update attribute values.
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadVertexData);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

    /*
     The texture vertices are set up such that we flip the texture vertically. This is so that our top left origin buffers match OpenGL's bottom left texture coordinate system.
     */
    GLfloat quadTextureData[] =  {
        1, 1,
        1, 0,
        0, 0,
        0, 1,
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, quadTextureData);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);

//    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(VertexIndexStruct) / sizeof(VertexIndexStruct[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &VertexIndexStruct);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle);
    [m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you loading the same images? Or are they different sizes? Looks like a possible alignment problem with the images. Try setting `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 1 if that's the case.

Comment: Setting GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT to 1 as @Reto Korai said, it works now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenGL texture tilted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983607/opengl-texture-tilted)

Comment: There is a new problem, now the colour is not correct on iPhone, see picture 2, the color seems to be rendered on the right of where it is expected to be